# How can I get a method to return a Random object of type NSObject

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I as a learning exercise of Objective C I need to write a method that returns a Random NSObject.
The approach that I tried to follow was to trying to get a list of all runtime objects and the itirate through and get an NSObject and return that.

Firstly I am not sure if that is the best approach. Secondly the code I am using is based on [this](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/wiki/getting-all-subclasses) and [objc_getClassList](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) link but in Xcode4 I am getting compile time error

```
warning: Semantic Issue: Implicit declaration of function 'objc_getClassList' is invalid in C99
warning: Semantic Issue: Implicit declaration of function 'classIsSubclassOfClass' is invalid in C99
```

I have tried adding following headers but no good

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/objc-class.h>
#import <objc/objc-runtime.h>
```

but neither helped me and still have the warning.

So can I please some help with these two things 
 1- Is this the right approach and what is if not to achieve what I am trying to achieve 
 2- How can I get [this code](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/wiki/getting-all-subclasses) to not give warnings in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `objc_getClassList` is declared in [`objc/runtime.h`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.3/runtime/runtime.h), so including or importing that should do it.

For the other part, you simply need to [declare your function](http://opencbp.sourceforge.net/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/opencbook/func.prototypes.html) before you use it. At the top level of the file, or in a file that you then include, you put the function header, without the body:

```
BOOL classIsSubclassOfClass( const Class aClass, const Class subclass );
```

This lets the compiler know about the function; you can then `#include` this declaration in any file that needs to use the function, while defining it (i.e., filling out the body) wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is to get a class, any class, that inherits from `NSObject`?

I do not think this is the right approach at all. I can not see the need to get any random class. What would you do with it?

Maybe what you want to is add a subset of known classes that are of use to use in an array. And then pick one at random from that array.